# Is there a clever way to do this with Docker (maybe via save/load/diff)?

Tags: docker

I have a large number of computers on which I can run code. However, I can only do so in "sessions", between which there is no file system persistence. I *do* at least have the ability outside of these sessions to  upload files to these hosts and this does persist. Basically, nothing these computers download themselves sticks, but I can choose to explicitly send them files.

Bandwidth is a big commodity on these computers.

Now, on these computers I run various docker images. If I `docker pull` some image, its going to be gone by the next session. I figured out that I can `docker save` an image on my computer, upload it to them (so it sticks), then at the beginning of every session they can `docker load`. In practice I'm sending them debian:wheezy, since most other images they need are based on that, thus even though there's still downloading repeated every session, at least its only the changes ontop of debian:wheezy.

My problem is as follows. Suppose I change the base debian:wheezy to something which we can call debian:cheesy (not a straight swap, something such that wheezy is in the image tree for cheesy), and that this significantly increases its size. Also, all my future images are now going to be based on cheesy, so I now want to upload cheesy to my computers.

Is there a way of sending them cheesy without somehow resending the data associated with wheezy?

Answer (score 1):

Docker save does not have the capability to copy partial images at this time. The initial design goal of save and load was to transfer images and all its dependencies between air gaped systems. (source: I am the initial author of save and load)

The problem is that while you may have debian:wheezy, how can you be sure that you have the same debian:wheezy between each system? The only sure way to have a successful save and load is to serialize the entire tree.

Instead, you should consider running a private docker registry. You can publish myorg:cheesy and let docker pull and docker push work out all the dependencies. This will also lower your overall bandwidth usage since only the layers you don't already have will be transmitted. It will also be much easier for you to manage in the long run.

To run your own private registry, you should check out https://github.com/docker/distribution which is an open source private repo. You can hop onto freenode's #docker-distribution if you need help from the developers.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen mention of running a private registry searching for an answer but I don't think I understand how it would work. Are you talking about running the private registry locally, and having my other computers pull from this? If so, I don't see how that changes anything, anything pulled even from this private registry during a session is lost. Now if you're talking about using my upload ability to send a copy of the private registry to each worker periodically, then perhaps I see what you're getting at but need to think about it more...

Comment: Btw, if this seems contrived, maybe I should mentioned, these are BOINC clients I'm talking about.

Comment: Yea, in that environment you are quite limited in options. My thought was you could stand up a registry outside of the BOINC environment and pull them in. Seed an up to date image on initial BOINC update (docker save is a good candidate for this) and set up the registry so that docker pull will pull in updates. This way you aren't pulling in debian or deps that don't change often, only your application changes.