# Docker save image difference

Tags: docker, deployment, containers, docker-layer

I'm deploying my application using Docker.

But I have some clients that doesn't allow me connect to any docker repository, for security reason.

To do the deploy, I'm saving all my images in a file:

```sh
docker save -o deploy.docker image-1 image-2...
```

When doing the deploy, I'm using `docker load`:

```sh
docker load < deploy.docker
```

There is any way to only save the layers that has changed from the previous version?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43320872/596285 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/31040045/596285

Comment: Yes, but is there no option in 2019?

Comment: No, there is no other option than running a registry, which docker provides for free, that you can run yourself in a fully disconnected environment. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320872/docker-how-can-we-export-import-or-save-load-only-the-new-changes#comment95654698_43413411